# MySQL query Not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to get data (the highest score for each category) from my database with the following query:

`SELECT category, score FROM scores GROUP BY category ORDER BY score DESC`

The problem is that it is not listing the scores in DESC order. For example, when I run this query, it says that the highest score for `General Studies` is `10` when the actual highest score is `25`. Here is what is returned with the query above:

[image]

However, whenever I run the following query without grouping by `category`, the `DESC score` works:

`SELECT category, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC`

Here is what is returned with the query above:

[image]

What I need is the categories to be grouped together with the highest score in the category being returned.

Comment: What is the datatype of score? (show us your create table).

Comment: Beware using `GROUP BY` in MySQL when you have `SELECT` columns not included in the `GROUP BY` and not in an aggregate function.  The result returned will be indeterminate, and that is the behavior you are seeing.  Most other RDBMS would result in a syntax error if you attempted your query.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include the `max` aggregate function here.  This will show the max score for each of the grouped results.

```
SELECT category, max(score)
FROM scores  
GROUP BY category 
ORDER BY max(score) DESC
```